# how do i output an rmarkdown file into a folder of my choosing?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have 2 scripts. One is an R script and the other an rmarkdown script.

I'm using the following code in the R script to run the markdown script:

```
rmarkdown::render("my_md_file_path_and_name.Rmd"))
```

I want to have the .html file it creates output into a folder of my choosing. At the moment it outputs into the same folder where the markdown script is stored.

Is this possible? I've done a lot of googling and although there's a lot of talk on this, i can't find anything which actually works. I'm not very familiar with markdown, so possibly there's a working solution i've read, but didn't fully understand how to code it into my script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `output_file` argument.

```
rmarkdown::render("my_md_file_path_and_name.Rmd", 
                  output_file = '/file/path/out.html')
```